# How to inject html into iframe, and display inside jquery-ui dialog

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, iframe

Here I create a jqueryui dialog from an iframe and populate the iframe with some html.

In firefox this displays nothing until I add the alert.  Is there a better way to convince firefox to draw the iframe?

http://jsfiddle.net/jtmx00f4/6/

```
function fancyDialog(htm) {
    $('<iframe></iframe>').dialog({
        open: function () {
            //alert('presto!');
            var doc = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;
            doc.body.innerHTML = htm;
        }
    });
}

fancyDialog('<html><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>');
```

Comment: You'd have to listen to the `load` event on the iframe. But then it doesn't seem to work in Chrome anymore, presumably because it does not trigger a load event there.

Comment: Well, for starters, you're injecting `<html><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>` into the existing `<body>` element, so the resulting markup will be ill-formed.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: inhjecting markup via the DOM will never result in ill-formed markup. valid? maybe, maybe not, but it will be well-formed.

Comment: @dan, sorry, I should have said the resulting *HTML* markup will be ill-formed -- `<html>` inside `<body>` is clearly not legal.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: the browser would never put html instead of body, at least not since html5...

Comment: @op: i don't normally suggest such, but i would think a short setTimeout would achieve the same effect as the alert does for you. since you're "loading" a frame without a src, it should be almost-instant in all browsers. edit: indeed: http://jsfiddle.net/jtmx00f4/7/

Answer (score 0):

While @dandavis fiddle does work in firefox, I also found a more complete solution in  [this article](https://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/inject-content-into-a-new-iframe/) which does not require setTimeout.

http://jsfiddle.net/jtmx00f4/9/

```
function fancyDialog(htm) {
    $('<iframe></iframe>').dialog({
        open: function () {
            this.contentWindow.contents = htm;
            this.src = 'javascript:window["contents"]';
        }
    });
}

fancyDialog('<html><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>');
```